# Implementing Autologin using VB Script

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to implement autologin to my site usinf VBscript and running it through batch command on cmd.

Auto login is getting done but also I am Getting below error:

VB Script Runtime error Object required Ipf
Please help why I am getting this error ?
Here is the Code

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate "mysitename"
IE.Visible = True

While IE.Busy
WScript.Sleep 50
Wend

Set ipf = IE.document.getElementByID("login")
ipf.Value = "loginid" 
Set ipf = IE.document.getElementByID("password")
ipf.Value = "password" 
Set ipf = IE.document.getElementByID("button")
ipf.Click
```

Answer (score 0):

Write `Dim ipf` before the sets.

You need to declare the objects first.

Comment: Now I am getting Object Required Error and one more thing if  I am excuting this script for first time it wont get htis error but second time it gives .

Comment: try and include `Set ipf = Nothing` at the end.